# NSSM - Trying to access Software/Google/DriveFS/Share

Tags: google-drive-api, nssm

I'm using [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/) to run a dotnet core app as a Windows service, which works really well.

However, I've noticed an error when I run `nssm install MyAppName`, which loads a window to set up the service. When I Select the executable to install, I notice that the following error is written to the console:

```
CreateDirectory : The system could not find the path specified. (3)
Could not initialize crash reporting DB
Can not init crashpad with status: CRASHPAD_DB_INIT_ERROR[23584] 
 registry_win.h:59:GetProtoFromRegistryValue Opening registry key Software\Google\DriveFS\Share failed with 0x2
```

I dont know much about NSSM nor Google DriveFS, but I'm wondering why I'm seeing this message - any ideas? My main concern is whether or not this is trying to access my Google Drive? Probably not - it seems a fairly reputable app, but I figure it's best to ask as someone will likely know better than me.